# Thunderbird does not show GMail folders

Tags: windows-10, email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I am running Thunderbird 45.2.0 on a Windows 10 Pro X64 desktop PC without any problems. I access 2 GMail accounts, and a Yahoo account for a couple of years.

I also access these accounts on a Windows 10 Pro X64 laptop running the same version of Thunderbird. Recently, the IMAP folders disappeared in Thunderbird.

I cannot retrieve the IMAP folders, even after uninstalling Thunderbird, deleting all unused folders in Program Files and in Appdata. I also removed unused registry keys in the hope of getting rid of any corruption associated with Thunderbird installation.

After installing Thunderbird again, the problem remains: I only see an Inbox folder for the accounts, no other accounts as are still available on the Desktop installation.

I selected imap.gmail.com port 993 as the IMAP server and smtp.gmail.com port 465 as SMTP server as Thunderbird suggested. I changed the authentication to Normal password, as used on the desktop PC. However, Thunderbird reports User Name or password incorrect. The user name and password I use is correct: I can log in to GMail in Windows Edge with the user name and password I try to use in the Thunderbird setup.

I suspect the problem to be with Thunderbird as I tried to copy the profile files from the desktop PC to the laptop but the problem persists, even with the Yahoo account.

Any suggestions to get this going on the laptop?

Comment: If you right-click on the account and select "subscribe", can you see the folders you're after?

Comment: I have since narrowed the problem to Avast Anti-Virus, not Thunderbird. When turning off the mail shield in Avast, everything works fine. I am now following it up on the Avast forum. Hopefully the problem can be quickly resolved.